# Can anyone help me setup my quectel mc60?

Tags: c, embedded, mqtt

Forgive me for my poor English.
I’m having trouble setting up my MC60 and need your help.
I am using MC60 in open cpu mode and using SDK version 1.8 to develop my module.
All parts of the module from GPS to Bluetooth work properly but when it comes to the program written with MQTT and I program it on the module. The module has problems and sometimes restarts itself.
But the data is sent. Does anyone have any idea why my module keeps restarting?

```
#ifdef __EXAMPLE_MQTT__
#include "custom_feature_def.h"
#include "ql_stdlib.h"
#include "ql_common.h"
#include "ql_system.h"
#include "ql_type.h"
#include "ql_trace.h"
#include "ql_error.h"
#include "ql_uart.h"
#include "ql_timer.h"
#include "ril_network.h"
#include "ril_mqtt.h"
#include "ril.h"
#include "ril_util.h"
#include "ril_system.h"


#define DEBUG_ENABLE 1
#if DEBUG_ENABLE > 0
#define DEBUG_PORT  UART_PORT1
#define DBG_BUF_LEN   1024
static char DBG_BUFFER[DBG_BUF_LEN];
#define APP_DEBUG(FORMAT,...) {\
    Ql_memset(DBG_BUFFER, 0, DBG_BUF_LEN);\
    Ql_sprintf(DBG_BUFFER,FORMAT,##__VA_ARGS__); \
    if (UART_PORT2 == (DEBUG_PORT)) \
    {\
        Ql_Debug_Trace(DBG_BUFFER);\
    } else {\
        Ql_UART_Write((Enum_SerialPort)(DEBUG_PORT), (u8*)(DBG_BUFFER), Ql_strlen((const char *)(DBG_BUFFER)));\
    }\
}
#else
#define APP_DEBUG(FORMAT,...) 
#endif


/*****************************************************************
* define process state
******************************************************************/
typedef enum{
    STATE_NW_QUERY_STATE,
    STATE_MQTT_CFG,
    STATE_MQTT_OPEN,
    STATE_MQTT_CONN,
    STATE_MQTT_SUB,
    STATE_MQTT_PUB,
    STATE_MQTT_TUNS,
    STATE_MQTT_CLOSE,
    STATE_MQTT_DISC,
    STATE_MQTT_TOTAL_NUM
}Enum_ONENETSTATE;
static u8 m_mqtt_state = STATE_NW_QUERY_STATE;

/****************************************************************************
* Definition for APN
****************************************************************************/
#define APN      "mtnirancelln\0"
#define USERID   ""
#define PASSWD   ""

/*****************************************************************
* MQTT  timer param
******************************************************************/
#define MQTT_TIMER_ID         0x200
#define MQTT_TIMER_PERIOD     500

/*****************************************************************
* Server Param
******************************************************************/
#define SRVADDR_BUFFER_LEN    100

//#define HOST_NAME             "yourproductkey.iot-as-mqtt.cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com"
#define HOST_NAME             "91.92.124.150"
#define HOST_PORT             1883

/*****************************************************************
* Uart   param
******************************************************************/
#define SERIAL_RX_BUFFER_LEN  2048
static Enum_SerialPort m_myUartPort  = UART_PORT1;
static u8 g_RxBuf_Uart1[SERIAL_RX_BUFFER_LEN];

/*****************************************************************
*  MQTT Param
******************************************************************/
MQTT_Urc_Param_t*     mqtt_urc_param_ptr = NULL;
ST_MQTT_topic_info_t  mqtt_topic_info_t;
bool DISC_flag  = TRUE;
bool CLOSE_flag = TRUE;

/*****************************************************************
*  Sample Param
******************************************************************/
Enum_ConnectID connect_id = ConnectID_0;
u32 pub_message_id = 0;
u32 sub_message_id = 0;

u8 product_key[] =   "0.6.1\0";   //<ali cloud needs it.
u8 device_name[]=    "MC60_1102\0";   //<ali cloud needs it.
u8 device_secret[] = "01120"; //<ali cloud needs it.
u8 clientID[] =      "MC60_01\0";
u8 username[] =      ".......\0";
u8 passwd[] =        ".......\0";

static u8 test_data[128] =  "just test send data!!\0"; //<first packet data
static u8 test_topic[128] = "The topic\0"; //<topic

/*****************************************************************
* Uart callback function
******************************************************************/
static void proc_handle(u8 *pData,s32 len);
static s32 ReadSerialPort(Enum_SerialPort port, /*[out]*/u8* pBuffer, /*[in]*/u32 bufLen);
static void CallBack_UART_Hdlr(Enum_SerialPort port, Enum_UARTEventType msg, bool level, void* customizedPara);

/*****************************************************************
* Timer callback function
******************************************************************/
static void Callback_Timer(u32 timerId, void* param);

/*****************************************************************
* MQTT recv callback function
******************************************************************/
static void mqtt_recv(u8* buffer,u32 length);


void proc_main_task(s32 taskId)
{
    ST_MSG msg;
    s32 ret;

    //<Register & open UART port
    Ql_UART_Register(m_myUartPort, CallBack_UART_Hdlr, NULL);
    Ql_UART_Open(m_myUartPort, 115200, FC_NONE);

    APP_DEBUG("//<------------OpenCPU: MQTT Client.------------\r\n");

    //<register state timer 
    Ql_Timer_Register(MQTT_TIMER_ID, Callback_Timer, NULL);

    //register MQTT recv callback
    ret = Ql_Mqtt_Recv_Register(mqtt_recv);
    APP_DEBUG("//<register recv callback,ret = %d\r\n",ret);

    while(TRUE)
    {
        Ql_OS_GetMessage(&msg);
        switch(msg.message)
        {
            case MSG_ID_RIL_READY:
                APP_DEBUG("//<RIL is ready\r\n");
                Ql_RIL_Initialize();
                break;
            case MSG_ID_URC_INDICATION:
                {     
                    switch (msg.param1)
                    {
                        case URC_SIM_CARD_STATE_IND:
                            {
                                APP_DEBUG("//<SIM Card Status:%d\r\n", msg.param2);
                                if(SIM_STAT_READY == msg.param2)
                                {
                                   Ql_Timer_Start(MQTT_TIMER_ID, MQTT_TIMER_PERIOD, TRUE);
                                   APP_DEBUG("//<state timer start,ret = %d\r\n",ret);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case URC_MQTT_OPEN:
                            {
                                mqtt_urc_param_ptr = msg.param2;
                                if(0 == mqtt_urc_param_ptr->result)
                                {
                                    APP_DEBUG("//<Open a MQTT client successfully\r\n");
                                    m_mqtt_state = STATE_MQTT_CONN;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    APP_DEBUG("//<Open a MQTT client failure,error = %d\r\n",mqtt_urc_param_ptr->result);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case URC_MQTT_CONN:
                            {
                                mqtt_urc_param_ptr = msg.param2;
                                if(0 == mqtt_urc_param_ptr->result)
                                {
                                    APP_DEBUG("//<Connect to MQTT server successfully\r\n");
                                    m_mqtt_state = STATE_MQTT_SUB;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    APP_DEBUG("//<Connect to MQTT server failure,error = %d\r\n",mqtt_urc_param_ptr->result);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case URC_MQTT_SUB:
                            {
                                mqtt_urc_param_ptr = msg.param2;
                                if((0 == mqtt_urc_param_ptr->result)&&(128 != mqtt_urc_param_ptr->sub_value[0]))
                                {
                                    APP_DEBUG("//<Subscribe topics successfully\r\n");
                                    m_mqtt_state = STATE_MQTT_PUB;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    APP_DEBUG("//<Subscribe topics failure,error = %d\r\n",mqtt_urc_param_ptr->result);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case URC_MQTT_PUB:
                            {
                                mqtt_urc_param_ptr = msg.param2;
                                if(0 == mqtt_urc_param_ptr->result)
                                {
                                    APP_DEBUG("//<Publish messages to MQTT server successfully\r\n");
                                    m_mqtt_state = STATE_MQTT_TOTAL_NUM;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    APP_DEBUG("//<Publish messages to MQTT server failure,error = %d\r\n",mqtt_urc_param_ptr->result);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case URC_MQTT_CLOSE:
                            {
                                mqtt_urc_param_ptr = msg.param2;
                                if(0 == mqtt_urc_param_ptr->result)
                                {
                                    APP_DEBUG("//<Closed MQTT socket successfully\r\n");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    APP_DEBUG("//<Closed MQTT socket failure,error = %d\r\n",mqtt_urc_param_ptr->result);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case URC_MQTT_DISC:
                            {
                                mqtt_urc_param_ptr = msg.param2;
                                if(0 == mqtt_urc_param_ptr->result)
                                {
                                    APP_DEBUG("//<Disconnect MQTT successfully\r\n");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    APP_DEBUG("//<Disconnect MQTT failure,error = %d\r\n",mqtt_urc_param_ptr->result);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            //APP_DEBUG("<-- Other URC: type=%d\r\n", msg.param1);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    Ql_Sleep(1000);
}

static s32 ReadSerialPort(Enum_SerialPort port, /*[out]*/u8* pBuffer, /*[in]*/u32 bufLen)
{
    s32 rdLen = 0;
    s32 rdTotalLen = 0;
    if (NULL == pBuffer || 0 == bufLen)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    Ql_memset(pBuffer, 0x0, bufLen);
    while (1)
    {
        rdLen = Ql_UART_Read(port, pBuffer + rdTotalLen, bufLen - rdTotalLen);
        if (rdLen <= 0)  // All data is read out, or Serial Port Error!
        {
            break;
        }
        rdTotalLen += rdLen;
        // Continue to read...
    }
    if (rdLen < 0) // Serial Port Error!
    {
        APP_DEBUG("//<Fail to read from port[%d]\r\n", port);
        return -99;
    }
    return rdTotalLen;
}

static void CallBack_UART_Hdlr(Enum_SerialPort port, Enum_UARTEventType msg, bool level, void* customizedPara)
{
    char *p = NULL;
    s32 ret;
    
    switch (msg)
    {
        case EVENT_UART_READY_TO_READ:
            {
                if(m_myUartPort == port)
                {
                    s32 totalBytes = ReadSerialPort(port, g_RxBuf_Uart1, sizeof(g_RxBuf_Uart1));
                    if (totalBytes <= 0)
                    {
                        APP_DEBUG("//<No data in UART buffer!\r\n");
                        return;
                    }
                    p = Ql_strstr(g_RxBuf_Uart1,"DISC");
                    if(p)
                    {
                        ret = RIL_MQTT_QMTDISC(connect_id);
                        if(RIL_AT_SUCCESS == ret)
                        {
                            APP_DEBUG("//<Start disconnect MQTT socket\r\n");
                            if(TRUE == DISC_flag)
                                DISC_flag  = FALSE;
                            m_mqtt_state = STATE_MQTT_TOTAL_NUM;
                        }else
                        {
                            APP_DEBUG("//<Disconnect MQTT socket failure,ret = %d\r\n",ret); 
                            m_mqtt_state = STATE_MQTT_TOTAL_NUM;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    p = Ql_strstr(g_RxBuf_Uart1,"CLOSE");
                    if(p)
                    {
                        ret = RIL_MQTT_QMTCLOSE(connect_id);
                        if (RIL_AT_SUCCESS == ret)
                        {
                            APP_DEBUG("//<Start closed MQTT socket\r\n");
                            if(TRUE == CLOSE_flag)
                                CLOSE_flag = FALSE;
                            m_mqtt_state = STATE_MQTT_TOTAL_NUM;
                        }else
                        {
                            APP_DEBUG("//<Closed MQTT socket failure,ret = %d\r\n",ret);
                            m_mqtt_state = STATE_MQTT_TOTAL_NUM;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    p = Ql_strstr(g_RxBuf_Uart1,"RECONN");
                    if(p)
                    {
                        if((FALSE == DISC_flag)||(FALSE == CLOSE_flag))
                        {
                            m_mqtt_state = STATE_MQTT_OPEN;
                            APP_DEBUG("\r\n");
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    //<The rest of the UART data is published as data.
                    {
                        if((TRUE == DISC_flag)&&(TRUE == CLOSE_flag))
                        {
                            pub_message_id++;  // The range is 0-65535. It will be 0 only when<qos>=0.
                            ret = RIL_MQTT_QMTPUB(connect_id,pub_message_id,QOS1_AT_LEASET_ONCE,0,test_topic,totalBytes,g_RxBuf_Uart1);
                            if (RIL_AT_SUCCESS == ret)
                            {
                                APP_DEBUG("//<Start publish a message to server\r\n");
                            }else
                            {
                                APP_DEBUG("//<Publish a message to server failure,ret = %d\r\n",ret);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //<No connection to the cloud platform, just echo.
                            APP_DEBUG("\r\n//<No connection to the cloud platform, just echo.\r\n");
                            Ql_UART_Write(m_myUartPort, g_RxBuf_Uart1, totalBytes);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case EVENT_UART_READY_TO_WRITE:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

static void mqtt_recv(u8* buffer,u32 length)
{
    APP_DEBUG("//<data:%s,len:%d\r\n",buffer,length);
}

static void Callback_Timer(u32 timerId, void* param)
{
    s32 ret;
    
    if(MQTT_TIMER_ID == timerId)
    {
        switch(m_mqtt_state)
        {        
            case STATE_NW_QUERY_STATE:
            {
                s32 cgreg = 0;
                ret = RIL_NW_GetGPRSState(&cgreg);
                APP_DEBUG("//<Network State:cgreg = %d\r\n",cgreg);
                if((cgreg == NW_STAT_REGISTERED)||(cgreg == NW_STAT_REGISTERED_ROAMING))
                {
                    //<Set PDP context 0
                    RIL_NW_SetGPRSContext(0);
                    APP_DEBUG("//<Set PDP context 0 \r\n");
                    //<Set APN
                    ret = RIL_NW_SetAPN(1, APN, USERID, PASSWD);
                    APP_DEBUG("//<Set APN \r\n");
                    //PDP activated
                    ret = RIL_NW_OpenPDPContext();
                    if(ret == RIL_AT_SUCCESS)
                    {
                        APP_DEBUG("//<Activate PDP context,ret = %d\r\n",ret);
                        m_mqtt_state = STATE_MQTT_CFG;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case STATE_MQTT_CFG:
            {
                //ret = RIL_MQTT_QMTCFG_Ali(connect_id,product_key,device_name,device_secret);//<This configuration is required to connect to Ali Cloud.
                RIL_MQTT_QMTCFG_Showrecvlen(connect_id,ShowFlag_1);//<This sentence must be configured. The configuration will definitely succeed, so there is no need to care about.
                ret = RIL_MQTT_QMTCFG_Version_Select(connect_id,Version_3_1_1);
                if(RIL_AT_SUCCESS == ret)
                {
                    //APP_DEBUG("//<Ali Platform configure successfully\r\n");
                    APP_DEBUG("//<Select version 3.1.1 successfully\r\n");
                    m_mqtt_state = STATE_MQTT_OPEN;
                }
                else
                {
                    //APP_DEBUG("//<Ali Platform configure failure,ret = %d\r\n",ret);
                    APP_DEBUG("//<Select version 3.1.1 failure,ret = %d\r\n",ret);
                }
                break;
            }
            case STATE_MQTT_OPEN:
            {
                ret = RIL_MQTT_QMTOPEN(connect_id,HOST_NAME,HOST_PORT);
                if(RIL_AT_SUCCESS == ret)
                {
                    APP_DEBUG("//<Start opening a MQTT client\r\n");
                    if(FALSE == CLOSE_flag)
                        CLOSE_flag = TRUE;
                    m_mqtt_state = STATE_MQTT_TOTAL_NUM;
                }
                else
                {
                    APP_DEBUG("//<Open a MQTT client failure,ret = %d-->\r\n",ret);
                }
                break;
            }
            case STATE_MQTT_CONN:
            {
                ret = RIL_MQTT_QMTCONN(connect_id,clientID,username,passwd);
                if(RIL_AT_SUCCESS == ret)
                {
                    APP_DEBUG("//<Start connect to MQTT server\r\n");
                    if(FALSE == DISC_flag)
                        DISC_flag = TRUE;
                    m_mqtt_state = STATE_MQTT_TOTAL_NUM;
                }
                else
                {
                    APP_DEBUG("//<connect to MQTT server failure,ret = %d\r\n",ret);
                }
                break;
            }
            case STATE_MQTT_SUB:
            {               
                mqtt_topic_info_t.count = 1;
                mqtt_topic_info_t.topic[0] = (u8*)Ql_MEM_Alloc(sizeof(u8)*256);
                
                Ql_memset(mqtt_topic_info_t.topic[0],0,256);
                Ql_memcpy(mqtt_topic_info_t.topic[0],test_topic,Ql_strlen(test_topic));
                mqtt_topic_info_t.qos[0] = QOS1_AT_LEASET_ONCE;
                sub_message_id++;  //< 1-65535.
                
                ret = RIL_MQTT_QMTSUB(connect_id,sub_message_id,&mqtt_topic_info_t);
                
                Ql_MEM_Free(mqtt_topic_info_t.topic[0]);
                mqtt_topic_info_t.topic[0] = NULL;
                if(RIL_AT_SUCCESS == ret)
                {
                    APP_DEBUG("//<Start subscribe topic\r\n");
                    m_mqtt_state = STATE_MQTT_TOTAL_NUM;
                }
                else
                {
                    APP_DEBUG("//<Subscribe topic failure,ret = %d\r\n",ret);
                }
                break;
            }
            case STATE_MQTT_PUB:
            {
                pub_message_id++;  //< The range is 0-65535. It will be 0 only when<qos>=0.
                ret = RIL_MQTT_QMTPUB(connect_id,pub_message_id,QOS1_AT_LEASET_ONCE,0,test_topic,Ql_strlen(test_data),test_data);
                if(RIL_AT_SUCCESS == ret)
                {
                    APP_DEBUG("//<Start publish a message to MQTT server\r\n");
                    m_mqtt_state = STATE_MQTT_TOTAL_NUM;
                }
                else
                {
                    APP_DEBUG("//<Publish a message to MQTT server failure,ret = %d\r\n",ret);
                }
                break;
            }
            case STATE_MQTT_TOTAL_NUM:
            {
                //<do nothing
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }    
    }
}

#endif // __EXAMPLE_MQTT__
```

This is the code I use on the module, which seems fine at first moments, but after the first connection and sending the first file, after each resending, the whole module starts from the beginning.